# Pyomo - how to write model.pprint() to file?

Tags: python, pyomo

I want to "debug" my pyomo model. The output of the `model.pprint()` method looks helpful but it is too long so the console only displays and stores the last lines. How can I see the first lines. And how can I store this output in a file

(I tried pickle, json, normal `f.write` but since the output of `.pprint()` is of type `NONE` I wasn't sucessfull until now. (I am also new to python and learning python and pyomo in parallel).

None of this works :
'''

```
with open('some_file2.txt', 'w') as f:
    serializer.dump(x, f)

import pickle 
object = Object() 
filehandler = open('some_file', 'wb') 
pickle.dump(x, filehandler)

x = str(instance)
x = str(instance.pprint()) 
f = open('file6.txt', 'w')
f.write(x)
f.write(instance.pprint())
f.close()
```

Comment: Does your model have a .pformat() method?  .pformat() is the non-printing, string-returning version of .pprint() for typical pprint objects.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `filename` keyword argument to the `pprint` method:

```
instance.pprint(filename='foo.txt')
```

Comment: works perfect! Thanks a lot! Can you give me a hint where I can find such informations. I am used to the help functions/documentations in R and Matlab but untill now I didn´t find a equivalent for pyomo/python.

Comment: Python also has a help function: `help(instance.pprint)` will print the docstring for the `pprint` method

Answer (score 2):

For me the accepted answer does not work, pprint has a different signature.

```py
help(instance.pprint)
pprint(ostream=None, verbose=False, prefix='') method of pyomo.core.base.PyomoModel.ConcreteModel instance

# working for me:
        with open(path, 'w') as output_file:
            instance.pprint(output_file)
```

Answer (score 0):

`instance.pprint()` prints in the console (stdout for standard output), but does not return the content (the return is `None` as you said). To have it print in a file, you can try to redirect the standard output to a file.

Try:

```
import sys
f = open('file6.txt', 'w')
sys.stdout = f
instance.pprint()
f.close()
```

It looks like there is a cleaner solution from Bethany =)